# how to Read and write salesforce data from Heroku for app

Tags: batch, integration, heroku

We are planning to create app, which will read data from salesforce, do processing and then write result back into salesforce. This operation will happen in 2 modes
1. Real time when user takes any action via visualforce page
2. Nightly Batch - This batch will be invoked from Salesforce or Heroku (Not decided yet) [100 to 200 records at once]

We are planning to create rest api hosted on Heroku and then salesforce can consume it. We prefer Java for Heroku. Please suggest if if this architecture is accurate or not. Any code samples, articles are also welcome.